# Можно ли передать файл в input[type=file] через js

Tags: javascript

Пишу userscript для одного сайта, который должен сымитировать отправку формы с файлом. Возможно ли вообще с помощью js загрузить файл на чужой сайт?

Comment: отправить файл на "чужой" сайт можно, но если его там никто не ждет, то и следов от него на сайте (сервере?) никаких не останется

Answer (score 1):

на сколько я знаю есть 2 варианта. 1й это используя айфрейм скрытый, а второй это используя объект FormData...почитайте вот тут:  http://code.biz.ua/articles/file-send-formdata-jquery/